# Is there any function in express to end a particular routing method in express without executing further?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-headers, httpresponse

so I have my post route here, what I wanna do is check if the user has met all the conditions about providing data in the body, and I am doing it by adding an if block to check if errors

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

  if(req.body.age < 24) {
    res.send("You are too young")
    // I want it to end here
  }

  // further logic
  console.log('still executing')

}
```

if the condition is not met it moves further, although if the conditions are met the further logic is still executing after sending the response, which I want it to end and it causes me further problems because I have other response for when the inputs are okay

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader
```

To tackle this things I have tried but haven't worked are

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {

  if(req.body.age < 24) {
    res.send("You are too young")
    res.end();
    // I want it to end here
  }

  // further logic
}
```

also tried direct ending by

```
 if(req.body.age < 24) {
    res.end("You are too young")
    // I want it to end here
  }
```

what works is returning and closing the function itself

```
 if(req.body.age < 24) {
    res.end("You are too young")
    return;
    // it ends here
  }
 // does not execute after return statement
```

so I wanted to know is there an express way to do it ? also reading about res.end too did not make much sense, because it should end the response as the document says, but does my other res.send initiate a new response ? and create cannot set headers problems ?

Comment: `return` *is* the Express way to do it - Express is based on JS, and if you don't `return` the function continues, so you either need an early return or for everything else to be in the `else` block. Note you should probably send a status code, in this case maybe 422.

Comment: okay makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no specific 'Express way' to do that. In Express, `Response.end()` is not a very good practice, you should always reply to the request. Here's how I would have done that:

```js
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
  if (req.body.age < 24) return res.status(403).send("You are too young"); // 403 => Forbidden. If you don't know what error code you should use, 400 always works.
  // Here, req.body.age >= 24
}
```

I added `.status(403)` to indicate that the error doesn't come from the server, but from the client input ; in this case their access is `Forbidden`. ([HTTP code cheatsheet here](https://devhints.io/http-status), it might be useful in the future) Otherwise, it would be `200` by default, and it means everything works fine, and that's not what you want to do.
In my snippet above, the request in answered, so everything is fine, and `Response.end()` would be useless. I think it's the most concise way to do the job (also, it's always better not to use a empty `return`). Hope I helped!